# NVMe device on my RHEL8 system corrupt?

Tags: namespace, nvme

It seems that the single namespace that was on my NVMe PCIe device is completely gone.  I received an email alert from my system which just said:

```
Device: /dev/nvme0, unable to open NVMe device
```

When I was able to check the system all of the partitions were not mountable or visible.  I rebooted and upon reboot the namespace wasn't there at all.  Nothing else had changed in the system so I have a feeling that it was corrupted somehow?  I just want to try and recover what is on the drive if possible.

Here are further details via the nvme cli:

dmesg on boot only shows this:

```
[    2.788717] nvme nvme0: pci function 0000:02:00.0
[    5.160208] nvme nvme0: 16/0/0 default/read/poll queues
```

`nvme list` doesn't show anything:

```
 nvme list                                                                                                                                         
Node                  SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev
--------------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
```

smartctl -i says that there is 0 unallocated capacity:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Number:                       HUSMR7632BHP301
Firmware Version:                   KNGNP100
PCI Vendor/Subsystem ID:            0x1c58
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x000cca
Total NVM Capacity:                 3,204,045,602,816 [3.20 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      35
Number of Namespaces:               128
Local Time is:                      Mon May  8 10:32:35 2023 PDT
```

Comment: It very well could be. Attach to a different PC - if it's still dead, it's dead.